# Forcing a lettrine to appear within a shifted block of bold text

Tags: lettrine

I am trying to compile an order of service which includes blocks of bold text which are indented from the actual margin. When I use a lettrine with normal text in this format it appears as expected (i.e. embedded within the text) but when I use it with bold text it appears outside the block as though it has ignored the indentation command. Does anybody know of a way to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.7mm}

\begin{document}

\textit{{\color{gregoriocolor}A period of silence for reflection on the past day may follow.}}

\textit{{\color{gregoriocolor}The following or other suitable words of penitence may be used.}}
\bigskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}

    \textbf{\lettrine{\textcolor{gregoriocolor}{W}}e confess to God almighty,\\
    the Father, the Son and the Holy Ghost,\\
    that we have sinned in thought, word and deed,\\
    through our own grievous fault.\\
    Wherefore we pray God to have mercy upon us.\\}

    \textbf{Almighty God, have mercy upon us,\\
    forgive us all our sins and deliver us from all evil,\\
    confirm and strengthen us in all goodness,\\
    and bring us to life everlasting;\\
    through Jesus Christ our Lord.\\
    Amen.\\}

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused, not by the indentation, but by putting a paragraph with a lettrine inside of `\textbf{...}`. The breakage isn’t as bad as it would be if you tried to put a paragraph break inside of `\textbf{...}`, but `lettrine` seems to produce a box that can be handled better by the declaration `\bfseries` than by the command `\textbf{...}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}% the geometry package is more recent and more powerful
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx,lettrine,libertine}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}% ex and em are better than mm: if you change font size, spacing will change proportionally
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{.02}% the lettrine is a little too small without this
\begin{document}
\textit{\color{gregoriocolor}A period of silence for reflection on the past day may follow.}% you had an extra set of braces here — not harmful, but clutters the source

\textit{\color{gregoriocolor}The following or other suitable words of penitence may be used.}

\bigskip

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}

{\bfseries
  \lettrine[lhang=.03]{\textcolor{gregoriocolor}{W}}{e} confess to God almighty,\\
  the Father, the Son and the Holy Ghost,\\
  that we have sinned in thought, word and deed,\\
  through our own grievous fault.\\
  Wherefore we pray God to have mercy upon us.% no \\ here: the blank line ends a paragraph

  Almighty God, have mercy upon us,\\
  forgive us all our sins and deliver us from all evil,\\
  confirm and strengthen us in all goodness,\\
  and bring us to life everlasting;\\
  through Jesus Christ our Lord.\\
  Amen.}

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that the command for lettrines takes two arguments: `\lettrine{}{}`, so you want `\lettrine{W}{e}` (which puts the ‘e’ in small caps).

I’ve set `lhang`, because, to the eye, lettrines look better aligned if they protrude a bit. How much they should protrude depends on the shape of the individual letter, so I haven’t set a default value.  I did set a default `Loversize`, but that’s appropriate only if all of your lettrines will be in this font; otherwise, you can set `loversize` as an optional argument to the `\lettrine` command.

While I don’t know what the whole document will look like, I suspect that you’ll find Libertine’s semibold series esthetically more pleasing than the bold.